# issues with 'Entity' in google app engine tutorial

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I have an issue with the GAE tutorial. I just started learning how to use it, and I came to face an issue with '@Entity' when I go to the localhost:8888 page to check the '@Entity' list in there, it shows an empty list.... and I don't understand why... I'm following the tutorial line by line !!!

```
@Entity
public class CheckIn {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Key key;
   private String placeId;
   private String userEmail;
   private Date checkinDate;
```

Comment: You have to create an object and put into the datastore before you can view it. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes ... I'm doing exactly what the tutorial is saying .... In the tutorial they hard coded the 1st entity

Comment: Can you give the link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

Comment: I'm in the section "Test Client and Backend Communication" Part 8

Comment: any help out there !?